# Person Life Event Component not showing up

Tags: lightning

I added the 'Life Events or Business Milestones' in the lightning page. Gave the Profiles that needed access to the 'Business Milestones' and 'Person Life Events' Object. But the user that has that profile still can't see it on the Page. Can someone please tell me what I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the community, what have you researched? Also, what configurations are in place for your lightning flexipage, the app, and the user's profile? Please review how to ask a question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation [Add the Life Event or Business Milestones Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_admin_guide.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_admin_add_life_event_comp.htm):

1. Add the related list to the Account, Person Account, and Contact page layout
2. Add the component to the record page (lightning flexipage)

Additional steps:

- IMPORTANT, add the "FSC Insurance" permission set [Set up Insurance for FSC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_admin_guide.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_insurance_admin_assign_permset.htm)
- Ensure user has the correct page layout assignment
- Ensure user has the correct lightning flexipage assignment for the app
- Double check object level and record level access
- Double check field level security for the user (profile / permission set)

Comment: Thank you gale-force-wizard! Adding the FSC Insurance worked!!!